# Live Unit Testing doesn't copy over data file used by test

Tags: visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

I have a test that loads and processes a .json file. The file is part of the project and marked as "copy always" so that it's present in the build directory of the test, and I have veryfied that this does work on manual test run.

Live Unit Testing instead disregards this setting and fails the test as the file is not found. Is there any option other then disabling the test for live testing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the file I wanted to read in a subfolder of my unit test project, and then stopping and starting Live Unit Testing